# How do I Change the Terraform Version in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I have installed the latest Terraform version, however in VSCode, in my directory when I type terraform --version  I get this.

```
Terraform v0.11.7
+ provider.azurerm v2.3.0

Your version of Terraform is out of date! The latest version
is 1.1.9. You can update by downloading from www.terraform.io/downloads.html
```

I have tried everything, even changed the path to the executable file in the settings, but nothing helped.

Comment: Which operating system are you using?

Comment: I am using Windows11

Comment: Assuming you are using Powershell, you can get the current executable path for Terraform with this command `Get-Command terraform`. You don't really specify how you installed Terraform, but you would want to make sure that command line environment actually  points to the correct terraform version.

Comment: Thank you very much, I deleted the file and now the command returns the path I set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Thank You [Ervin Szilagyi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7661119/ervin-szilagyi) for your suggestion, Tested in my enviorment working fine for me.**

You need to update the version of terraform exectutable file in the exectable path of terrform. To get the current executable path for Terraform with this command `Get-Command terraform`.

[image]

You can use this [***link***](https://www.terraform.io/downloads) to download the exectubale file.

[image]

Comment: I already had the executable file, but it wasn't recognised until I deleted the wrong version. After that it worked!